# Segmentation of objects in an image using opencv

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with several objects. Inorder to apply `cvFloodFill` operation on it, i require the seed points of each object as a parameter. How do i find the seed points? also how to find other parameters like new value, lo_diff and up_diff? 
Or If there is any other way of filling the image..please suggest!

Answer (score 2):

```
void cvFloodFill(CvArr* image, 
                 CvPoint seed_point, 
                 CvScalar new_val, 
                 CvScalar lo_diff = cvScalarAll(0), 
                 CvScalar up_diff=cvScalarAll(0), 
                 CvConnectedComp* comp=NULL, 
                 int flags=4, 
                 CvArr* mask=NULL)
```

[According to the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#floodfill), `seed_point` is the x,y coordinate that marks the starting point of the operation. If you look at [this example](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut4.html), the last image of [this group](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/opencvtut4-1.png) shows the result of the `cvFloodFill()` operation demonstrated on *Step 1: Filter Examples*.

`newVal`, `loDiff` and `upDiff` are parameters you need to experiment with until you find a value that gives you a good result.